# What is the order of execution of instruction in creating server in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-development-server

Can anyone explain which instruction is getting executed first. **http.createServer()** or **server.listen** and when callback function inside createserver will execute?

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Given `.listen()` is called on the return value of `createServer()`, there's only one possible order. Regarding when the callback is called, check the [documentation of the method](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener).

Comment: Surely it's the order of the __callbacks__ provided to `createServer` and `listen` that you're asking about, not the functions themselves, right?  I think you need to reword your question to clarify that.  Where you said _instruction_ I think you meant to say _callback_.  And you're talking about http.createServer's callback or server.listen's callback.  The way you worded it, it sounds like you're asking about which order the functions themselves will be called in.  And surely there's no question about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the NodeJS documentation for the HTTP module here:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener

You'll see what the http.createServer call returns, from the docs:

```
Returns a new instance of http.Server.
```

Thus the createServer call must complete before it can return a server object. Which is being used in your the server.listen call being made a few lines below. Asynchronous in NodeJS doesn't mean random.

Answer (score 0):

**http.createServer()** is the first to execute because the variable **server** must be set before use to avoid undefined error. And the **http.createServer** is a synchrone function [asynchronous-vs-synchronous](https://www.outsystems.com/blog/posts/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-programming/)

Comment: when callback function inside createServer exexute?

Comment: The callback is waiting for requests before called. The request can be from browser, postman, curl or something like that

Comment: The callback to `createServer` is a handler for requests. You'll see the "Server running..." log message occur as soon as the server is in a listening state, and that will happen before any requests come in to be handled by the `(req, res)` handler.